# Open default browser from wxPython GUI app packed by PyInstaller

Tags: python, wxpython, pyinstaller

I have Python 3.7.5 app with wxPython Phoenix GUI packed to .exe by PyInstaller 3.6. Freezing was with such params:

```
venv\Scripts\pyinstaller app.pyw --clean --onefile --windowed --add-binary icon.ico;. --add-binary logo-iconic.ico;. --add-binary vendor.exe;. --icon logo-iconic.ico --version-file file_version_info.txt
```

I'm trying to open link (for example, https://google.com) on button click in app window without showing console window.

What I tried:

- `wx.LaunchDefaultBrowser('https://google.com')`
- `subprocess.Popen('C:\\Windows\\explorer.exe https://google.com')`
- [Recipe](https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/wiki/Recipe-subprocess) from PyInstaller wiki

If I delete `--windowed` from PyInstaller params, app worked as expected with `wx.LaunchDefaultBrowser('https://google.com')`, but console window shows on app start. If redirect stdout and stderr to file as in PyInstaller recipe, I see nothing, file not created.

How to open default OS browser in PyInstaller packed Python app with wxPython GUI without console appearing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `webbrowser` module, part of the stdlib:

```py
from webbrowser import open
open('http://google.com')
```

This will open `google.com` in the users default browser.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! That was a bug in my code, which block web browser opening. Your answer is right, `wx.LaunchDefaultBrowser('https://google.com')` also work correctly